# A proof of the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove this theorem is valid and sufficient use the argument that if there is an injection function $f$ between the sets A and B and there is an injection function $g$ between B and A. The bijection function is $f\bigcup g$?

Comment: $f \cup g$ is a function from $A \cup B$ to $A \cup B$. I don't know whether it's a bijection or not, but it's certainly not the bijection in the theorem. There are lots of proofs online.

Comment: If there is an injection function between A and B, there is a bijection function between a sub-set of A and B. If there is an injection function between B and A, there is a bijection function of sub-set of B and A. As a definition, a function is an ordered pair so the union of one of these functions and the inverse of another is a bijection function between A and B.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen Let $A=B=\mathbb N$ and both functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are given by $f(n)=g(n)=n+1$. Now, $(2,3)\in f$, and $(2, 1)\in g^{-1}$ so both $(2, 3)$ and $(2, 1)$ belong to $f\cup g^{-1}$. Thus $f\cup g^{-1}$ is not even a function.

Comment: I found the correct way to do this in https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/CanBer.pdf. It is more complicated but the idea is the same.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen I'm glad you found a correct proof. But don't kid yourself - these are far from the same idea!

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

No, the proof shows that *if* we have an injection $f : A \to B$ and also an injection $g:B \to A$, then we have some bijection between $A$ and $B$. This bijection is typically  *not* $f \cup g$; it's more complicated than that. Many proofs can be found online, showing how to find such a bijection.